# Fetching Random User defined variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

> I have user defined variable like this.

```
url_1
url_2
url_3
.
.
.
url_n
```

> In HTTP Request sampler i have to randomly select any one of these URL's .So in server name textbox i am trying this ${url_${__Random(1,7)}} But it is not fetching the variable. How can i fetch the value of that variable.
>   I am also getting the following error.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://${url_${__Random(1,7)}}/ at java.net.URI$Parser.fail
```

Comment: try `evalVar` http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar.

Comment: good. you can add it as an answer, so others can be benefited.

Comment: ${__evalVar(url_${__Random(1,9)})} will fetch the variable url_1,url_2,............url_n randomly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

```
${__V(url_${__Random(1,7,)})}
```

As per function documentation:

> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> - **${A1}** - works OK
> - **${A${N}}** - does not work (nested variable reference)
> - **${__V(A${N})}** - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

If you need more information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)